# Simultaneous integration test using the same SQL database best practices

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, testing, integration-testing

My .NET Framework application talks to a SQL DB using Entity Framework. I'm trying to develop an integration test for the application. Right now the way I do it is to clean up the SQL DB during the test setup phrase, i.e every time I run the test, the test will start off with a clean db.

However, if 2 people run the same time roughly at the same time, I might run into trouble since both people are reading and writing **the same DB at the same time.**

I did some research, looks like the best way is to provision a new DB in the setup and delete the db during teardown.

I wonder if there is a simpler approach? Thanks.

Comment: are you using EF?  Is this .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: Yes I'm using Entity Framework. And it's .NET Framework. Let me edit the post

Comment: Sorry, I was going to suggest Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory but as you are not using EF Core, that will not help you.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory/

Comment: @JasonH, thanks for the suggestion. Dumb question, what's the difference between the EF and EF core? Just googled but seems like the answer is not very straightforward.

Comment: There is EF 6.x (which is the 'old' EF if you will and was built for .NET Framework).  EF Core 2.x (which is the 'new' EF) is a complete redesign of the EF classes and was originally build to run on .NET Core.  I say originally because you can run EF Core on .NET Framework based projects but you have to do several things to make it run smoothly.